# VBA Excel Comparing Values in two different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to compare the values in two columns that are located in different sheets. When a match is found I want to decrease the value in a third column that is in the same row as the matched values. I know how to hard code it below but I would rather not have to include this code for every row in excel.

```
If Range("g12").Value = Worksheets("Inventory Levels").Range("b2").Value Then
    Worksheets("Inventory Levels").Range("c2").Value = Worksheets("Inventory Levels").Range("c2").Value - 1
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a simple loop, see my comments for details.

```
Dim i as Integer
' Use "With" to fully qualify your sheet objects.
With ThisWorkbook
' Loop over rows 2 to 20 (change this as necessary)
For i = 2 to 20
    ' Use ampersand (&) for concatenation of strings
    If .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & (i + 10)).Value = .Sheets("Inventory Levels").Range("B" & i).Value Then
        .Sheets("Inventory Levels").Range("C" & i).Value = .Sheets("Inventory Levelts").Range("C" & i).Value - 1
    End If
Next i
End With
```